# Style background image URL depending on variable from HTML - Angular

Tags: html, angular, styles

I am trying to create a `div` with a background of an image depending one picture.

I have tried this:

```
<div
  *ngIf="persona.photoURL"
  class="photo"
  style="background-image: url({{persona.photoURL}})"
></div>
```

but I get a `div` with an empty background. I know that `bet.photoURL` has a value. How could I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `ngStyle`

```
<div
  *ngIf="persona.photoURL"
  class="photo"
  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + persona.photoURL + ')'}"
></div>
```

Comment: Made my day, buddy. I will mark it as correct as soon as I can